Long-formatting several sets of similarly named of variables in an R data.frame
I have several sets of columns whose names are related. For example, in the toy DATA below, one set of variables start with OTE_ and another set of variables start with RAE_.
In my actual data, I have several more sets of these similarly named variables. But as a starting point, I'm wondering how I can reformat my DATA so I achieve my Desired_output below.
DATA <- read.table(header=T, text=
"InstNm    OTE_CPct OTE_L OTE_P    OTE_R      RAE_EPct RAE_NPct RAE_L RAE_B RAE_P  RAE_R
 Baker          60      1     1  Limited            56     76     1     0     1   Limited")


Desired_output <- read.table(header=T, text=
"InstNm    Indicator Rating  CPct NPct  EPct  L   P  B
 Baker     OTE      Limited  60   NA    NA    1   1  NA
 Baker     RAE      Limited  NA   76    56    1   1  0")


DATA |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-InstNm, names_sep = "_", names_to = c("Indicator", ".value"))

Result
# A tibble: 2 × 9
  InstNm Indicator  CPct     L     P R        EPct  NPct     B
  <chr>  <chr>     <int> <int> <int> <chr>   <int> <int> <int>
1 Baker  OTE          60     1     1 Limited    NA    NA    NA
2 Baker  RAE          NA     1     1 Limited    56    76     0

